# How do I create a rank table for a given pandas dataframe with multiple numerical columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

I would like to create a rank table based on a multi-column pandas dataframe, with several numerical columns.

Let's use the following df as an example:

| Name | Sales | Volume | Reviews |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1000 | 100 | 100 |
| B | 2000 | 200 | 50 |
| C | 5400 | 500 | 10 |

I would like to create a new table, ranked_df that ranks the values in each column by descending order while maintaining essentially the same format:

| Name | Sales_rank | Volume_rank | Reviews_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 3 |

Now, I can iteratively do this by looping through the columns, i.e.

```
df = pd.DataFrame{
"Name":['A', 'B', 'C'], 
"Sales":[1000, 2000, 5400], 
"Volume":[100, 200, 500], 
"Reviews":[1000, 2000, 5400]
}

# make a copy of the original df
ranked_df = df.copy()

# define our interested columns
interest_cols = ['Sales', 'Volume', 'Reviews']
for col in interest_cols:
    ranked_df[f"{col}_rank"] = df[col].rank()

# drop the cols not needed 
...
```

But my question is this: is there a more elegant - or pythonic way of doing this? Maybe an apply for the dataframe? Or some vectorized operation by throwing it to numpy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Name').rank().reset_index()

    Name    Sales   Volume  Reviews
0   A       1.0     1.0     1.0
1   B       2.0     2.0     2.0
2   C       3.0     3.0     3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use transform/apply to hit each column

```py
df.set_index('Name').transform(pd.Series.rank, ascending = False)

      Sales  Volume  Reviews
Name
A       3.0     3.0      1.0
B       2.0     2.0      2.0
C       1.0     1.0      3.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Accepting this as answer for now, but would be interested in comparing the approaches that may also work  and the time they may take when the dataframe scales (e.g. transform vs directly ranking the entire df as the answer below). Appreciate it.

Comment: the other answer is better, since it works on the entire dataframe, and should be picked as the right answer.